# AWS 1 gb of EBS snapshot storage at 100%, but I don't have any snapshots or AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 on AWS (everything in the free tier) and today I got an alert about it exceeding the snapshot storage limit. Now what bugs me is that my machine has not run for over a day, nor have I created new ones. As the title says I don't have any snapshots or images either. I know it's only 5c/gb, but still, I don't want to see random charges from AWS.

Hope someone can explain this to me, thanks for any input!

Comment: Was it an alert you setup? What exactly does it say? Do the snapshots show on your bill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had snapshot in a different region and it wasn't displaying on the global view.